# URL alias for taxonomy in drupal 7

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

On a Drupal 7 site with pathauto installed I'm using a view to show all taxonomy terms of a given node. The terms are linked to the term's page. The problem is, that the path of those terms does not use the url alias' that are set for the terms. Is there a way (without programmatically rewrite the view) to use alias in a view?

I know about the globalredirect module, but a redirect is not a clean solution here, in my opinion. And I do not understand why the pathes aren't replaced by there aliases in a view, can someone explain please?

Comment: Need help please.

Comment: When listing terms, Views uses the aliases by default. How does your view know which node to show terms for? Contextual filters?

Comment: Thank you.
I managed to make it work.
I just create a template in which I made a loop on view The display to manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="nos_produits" class="grids_of_3 grids_of_3_accueil">

<?php 


$field = $view->result;
?>

<?php 

    foreach($field as $obj){


     $url = drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'taxonomy/term/'. $obj->tid);

?>
<div id="nos_produits" class="grids_of_3 grids_of_3_accueil">
<div class="grid1_of_3 div_cat_accueil">

    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">
        <div>
            <p><span><?php echo $obj->taxonomy_term_data_name;?></span></p>
        </div>
        <img src="http://faliam.com/demo/sites/default/files/styles/catalogueimage/public/catalogue/<?php echo $obj->_field_data['tid']['entity']->field_illustration['und'][0]['filename'];  ?>" alt="" height="300" width="368">

    </a>


    </div>
    </div>

<?php

}

?>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I'm interested for a better solution.
Thanks: o)