# Use taxonomy path-alias

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I've been <strike>working</strike> playing with the Facet API Search lately and I liked a lot the option that Facet API provides to use the alias of the taxonomies in the URL.

I was wondering if there is a chance to do the same in the Views. eg to be able to use the taxonomy alias as a token to construct a link. What I would like to achieve is to be able to construct in the Views a URL that can take me to a Faceted Search page so I can pre-filter it.

I know that is a bit redundant to be doing it, but for the project I work on, is something that was specifically requested. In the Views, there is no way to be able to get the alias of a taxonomy as a field. The only things I've seen so far, is to mimic the re-writing of taxonomy using PHP code [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/671400) and [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145046/url-alias-for-taxonomy-in-drupal-7?rq=1) .

I tried to find a module that would help use the alias but nothing had come up. Also, here in the forum, I had found similar issues but nothing related to my question about taxonomies.

[How to filter a View with Taxonomy alias](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3425/filter-with-taxonomy-term-alias-instead-of-term-id)

[Get a node alias as a field value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21258/get-a-url-alias-as-a-field-value?lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I managed to do this via a module I wrote.

To whom it may concern, the idea is to create a hook override for the [hook field formatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7.x).